# Why document.getElementsByClassName is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, html

Why my fiddle is not working as expected?

```
<button class="example"> Expirience </button>



var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

x.onClick = function() {
  console.log('Hello')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xrkjvt57/18/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
console.log(x)

x[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
console.log('Hello')
});
```

```html
<button class="example"> Expirience </button>
```

Comment: I also want to add to this, `.onclick` is the proper case when using @MountainConqueror's syntax.

Comment: @JohnPavek do you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/xrkjvt57/51/?

Answer (score 2):

getElementsByClassName returns an array.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code, here is a working example with comments as to what was wrong.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

// x is an array, you need to loop over the elements in the array
for(var i =0; i < x.length; i++)
  // onClick is not how you add a click handler, use addEventListener and 'click'
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('Hello')
  });
```

```css
.example {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="example"> Expirience </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var x = document.querySelector(".example");

    x.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Hello')
    });
```

```html
<button class="example"> Expirience </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a `NodeList` of elements, so you have to loop over them and handle each one individually. In addition, the event handler is all lowercase (`onclick`). You want:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function (button) {
 button.onclick = function() {
       console.log('Hello');
 }
})
```

```html
<button class="example"> Expirience </button>
```